# about collection view, the corner cell doesn't keep the backgroundColor even though i change it

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, collectionview

I'm making a collection view that has 6 * 7 cells and even though I wrote code such that I could change each cells background colour after declaring the `UICollectionView`; the cell background colour stays white. Other cells are not returning back to white background colour. Can someone tell me the reason why only this cell doesn't keep it's background colour?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressAction(_:)))
    longPressRecognizer.allowableMovement = 5
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let col = indexPath.section
    let row = indexPath.row

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTableCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    if !ViewController.colorDictionary.isEmpty {
        for (indexPath, color) in ViewController.colorDictionary {
            self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should research about reusing of cells in collections. This may help you

Comment: Please debug the dictionary if condition. It might be going in if statement everytime cell gets return from the collection view.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that only one cell in the corner doesn't change it's background color

Answer (score 0):

Please debug the dictionary if condition. It might be going in if statement everytime cell gets return from the collection view.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that only one cell in the corner doesn't change it's background color